# Strange behavior when rendering html in email

Tags: python, smtp, mime

Encountering some super weird behavior with sending html emails using `smtplib` and `email.mime`. It appears that the email html interpreter is failing to read some html tags properly. The behavior changes if we modify `x` and `y` in code below, but remains consistent for same `x,y` values (i.e `x=2, y=3` as in example below will always produce same spot where html breaks, but a different combo will break in another spot). Also, in this example, commenting the `body += f'<b>Subsection {j}</b><br>'` line, will produce different behavior. Not sure what's happening here.

Code:

```
import random
import smtplib

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

def main():
    sender_email = sender
    message = MIMEMultipart()
    subject = 'html email testing'
    recipients = recipients
    message['Subject'] = subject  
    message['From'] = sender_email
    message['To'] = ', '.join(recipients)

    x = 2
    body = 'Hello,<br><br>This is a email to test when html gets messed up in outlook.<br><br>'
    for i in range(x):
        body += f'<h4>Section {i}</h4>'
        y = 3
        for j in range(y):
            body += f'<b>Subsection {j}</b><br>'
            body += f'<b>Item 1:</b> <span style="color:red">some items</span><br>' 
            body += f'<b>Item 2:</b> <span style="color:red">some items, blah blah</span><br>'
            body += f'<b>Item 3:</b> <span style="color:red">some items</span><br>'
            body += f'<b>Item 4:</b> <span style="color:red">some items</span><br>'
            body += f'<b>Item 5:</b> <span style="color:red">some items, more items</span><br>'
            body += f'<b>Item 6:</b> <span style="color:red">some items</span><br>'
            body += '<br><hr><br>'

    message.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))

    with smtplib.SMTP(f'localhost:{port}') as server:
        server.sendmail(sender_email, recipients, message.as_string())
```

Included ss of output. You can run this example by using different `x,y` values and/or adding/removing lines from `body`. I've tested this on both gmail and outlook. If I print `message` before I send it, I see that all tags are closed properly. However, the span tag isn't closed properly in this case when viewing the outlook and gmail original message.

[image][image]

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem. If you save HTML from Outlook and it looks OK (in text editor) but Outlook display it in wrong way then it is only problem with Outlook and it has nothing to do with `Python` and module `smtp`

Comment: I've tested in both gmail and outlook. Same result. The point is, is that there IS a problem, I am not sure where the problem lies, whether its an email interpreter or a problem with one of the modules I'm using.

Comment: You could save HTML directly in file and open in web browser to see if it has also this problem. It looks like one of `<span>` (which set red color) is missing closing tag `</span>` but I don't see this problem in code. You could get HTML which you get in Gmail and Outlook and compare with HTML in file to see if it was changed.

Comment: `<b>Subsection 1</b><br><b>Item 1:</b> <span style="color:red">some items</span><br><b>Item 2:</b> <span style="color:red">some items, blah blah</span><br><b>Item 3:</b> <span style="color:red">some items</
 span>` This is the gmail html, looks like a couple empty chars after beginning of closing the span tag could be an issue?

Comment: and outlook shows: `<b>Subsection 1</b><br><b>Item 1:</b> <span style="color:red">some items</span><br><b>Item 2:</b> <span style="color:red">some items, blah blah</span><br><b>Item 3:</b> <span style="color:red">some items</>` so doesn't register the closing span tag

Comment: first you should check what you have in `body` before sending. I used your code to send it with two differen mailboxes `poczta.o2.pl:587` and `gmail`  `smtp.googlemail.com:465` and both send it correctly. You uses some unknow `localhost` and it can make problem.

Comment: The body is correct. I connect to a work server, that's why it's localhost

Comment: you should check it with other server. If other server will send it correctly then problem is local server.

Comment: Yep, it's a server related issue. Thanks for the help